# Is the website directory path length important for server operations speed in any sense?

Tags: windows-server-2008, path, page-speed

I'm using a website and I do lots of operations (its a basis for mobile app).

If I place the website in a long path directory of the server will that slow down the operations in any sense?

I mean something like using

```
D:/websites/mobileapps/website
```

instead of

```
D:/website
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If i place the website in a long path directory of the server will
>   that slow down the operations in any sense?

No, it will not.